# Is there a way to get a horizontal ul to run off the page instead of wrapping without using relative positioning?

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have an unordered list element displaying list items across a horizontal row (inline), but the content is wider than the containing element. Is there a way to get them to simply run off the page instead of dropping to a new line without using absolute positioning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure there is, just use:

```
ul {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uruu8/).

This forces the contained content to continue along one, non-wrapping, line.

References:

- [`white-space` property, at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/white-space).

Answer (score 0):

Simply style the container with `white-space: nowrap;`.